# CURL , как постоянно прослушивать и изменить отображение в консоли

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

Вообщем прослушиваю через `curl -n url_обработчика` . На входящие POST запросы.
Через некоторое время прослушка просто прерывается, и надо заново перенабирать комманду. Каким образом сделать так чтоб время сессии было вечно,или был реконнект, и как сделать так, чтоб входящие параметры отображались более читабильно, с новой строки. Сейчас отображение подобное`{"time":"2018-03-28T07:19:26.423Z","data":{"id":373315,"uuid":"75541dc0-2e67-41c2-ae5c11626146c21e","type":"SaleReceiptRequest","status":"pending","kkt_receipt_id":null,"amount":"200.0","cash_amount":"0.0","electron_amount":"200.0","`, что крайне неудобно для меня , хотелось-бы чтоб каждый объект был с новой строки.

Comment: `keepAliveTimeout` у сервера выставьте.

Comment: Ну и `Keep-Alive` заголовок установить.